# Node.js effects in Thermite for Electron

Tags: reactjs, electron, purescript

I am trying to expand https://github.com/kRITZCREEK/electron-apps-with-purescript to add an input for the directory whose filenames I would display.

However, I cannot get the following function to typecheck (the last two lines are problematic, the last is line 53):

```
performAction :: T.PerformAction _ State _ Action
performAction (SetEditText s)           _ _ = void do
  T.cotransform $ _ { dir = s }
performAction (UpdateFiles s)           _ _ = void do
   filenames <- either (const []) id <$> try (readdir s)
   T.cotransform $ _ { names = filenames }
```

Here readdir is from Node.FS.Sync and has the signature

```
forall eff. String -> Eff (fs :: FS, err :: EXCEPTION | eff) (Array String)
```

and performAction is of type

```
forall t39 t40. Action -> t40 -> {dir :: String, names :: Array String} -> FreeT (CoTransform (Maybe {dir :: String, names :: Array String}) ({dir :: String, names :: Array String} -> {dir :: String, names :: Array String}))
```

The actual error is

```
Could not match type at line 53 col 4

FreeT
  (CoTransform t2
     ({ files :: t3
      | t4
      }
      -> { files :: Array String
         | t4
         }
     )
  )
with type
Eff
while trying to match type FreeT
                         (CoTransform t2
                            ({ files :: t3
                             | t4
                             }
                             -> { files :: Array String
                                | t4
                                }
                            )
                         )
                         t5
with type Eff
          ( fs :: FS
          | t0
          )
while checking that expression (apply cotransform) (\$1 ->
                                                  $1 { files = f
                                                     }
                                               )
has type Eff
         ( fs :: FS
         | t0
         )
         t1
in value declaration performAction
where t1 is an unknown type
  t0 is an unknown type
  t2 is an unknown type
  t5 is an unknown type
  t4 is an unknown type
  t3 is an unknown type
```

(The whole project can be found under https://github.com/MarkusBarthlen/electron-apps-with-purescript/blob/master/src/Main.purs)

I suspect I have to use any of lift/liftEff/liftEff'/liftAff. However,

```
performAction :: T.PerformAction _ State _ Action
performAction (UpdateFiles s)           _ _ = void do
   filenames <-  ( lift (either (const []) id <$> try (readdir s)))
   T.cotransform $ _ { names = filenames }
```

results in

```
    Could not match type at line 55 col 47
    Eff
     with type
    Aff
    while trying to match type Eff
                         ( fs :: FS
                         | t1
                         )
    with type Aff t0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it work with:

```
performAction :: forall e. T.PerformAction (fs :: FS | e) State _ Action
performAction (SetEditText s)           _ _ = void do
  T.cotransform $ _ { dir = s }
performAction (UpdateFiles s)           _ _ = void do
   filenames <- lift (liftEff (either (const []) id <$> try (readdir s)))
   T.cotransform $ _ { names = filenames }
  -- T.cotransform $ _ { dir = ""}
```

`liftEff` takes your `Eff` to an `Aff` and `lift` then raises that into the `FreeT ...` that Thermite uses. The extra `lift` shouldn't be necessary, but I think the problem is type inference around rows and typeclasses here and the situation should get better with the next release where we'll most likely have functional dependencies.

Comment: Awesome! If I ever meet you, I will have to buy you a beer.